# Starting a new screen session to run a script that starts another one

Tags: linux, node.js, bash, terminal

I'm trying to make a program using node.js that needs to be able to pull new updates and restart it self. For that purpose, I've made an auto.sh script that has this code in it:

```
screen -S GNode -X quit
screen -dmS GNode -L node server
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run that script from node, what appears to happen is that the first line is ran and my node application shuts down (as it's being run in that session) but then the second line doesn't get executed, which is a bummer.

What I've ended up doing is having ANOTHER screen session called ScriptRunner that I run with the command

```
screen -dmS ScriptRunner sh auto.sh
```

For some reason though, when I run that command and then check for open screen sessions, there are none. So the first line again gets executed but the second one doesn't. This doesn't appear to be a problem with my node program because when I run that last command directly in the terminal, the same thing happens.

Does anyone know what could possibly be wrong? I'm very new to Linux and terminal stuff.

Comment: Can tyou run `screen -dmS GNode -L node server` only without a session? Through `auto.sh` that is and not manually from terminal.

Comment: As I said, only the first line gets executed. The one that terminates the screen session that is runnig the script.

Comment: I was just considering that perhaps `screen -S GNode -X quit` is causing `screen -dmS GNode -L node server` to not run that's why it's good to verify that `screen -dmS GNode -L node server` indeed doesn't work even when ran alone. Just make sure that no session is running that you have to quit it first.

Comment: It works alone. In fact, when I call my script from the terminal (so the session that's calling it isn't the one that will terminate) it works as it's supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a delay before running the next session:

```
screen -S GNode -X quit
sleep 10s  ## You can adjust this value.
screen -dmS GNode -L node server
```

Comment: I'll try it but why would it work when I run the script manually?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference it seems.

Comment: @LukaHorvat Perhaps the next screen command just runs too fast not giving enough time for the previous session to exit.

Comment: I see. Sorry if it didn't help.

Comment: @LukaHorvat Perhaps you're running it as a different user. Try to add `whoami >/tmp/whoami.txt` and check the file after running.

Comment: That's not it. It says root running it one way or another.

Comment: @LukaHorvat I might be wrong but aren't you running it through `node.js`? If that's the case, won't the script be called as the user of the server process? Or are you implying that it would still run anyway even as that kind of user?

Comment: The thing is, when I run the script manually using sh auto.sh in the terminal it works fine (the user is root). But when I run it using "screen -dmS ScriptRunner sh auto.sh" in the terminal manually OR in my node app, the result is always the same and it doesn't restart the screen. The user is still root if I run "screen -dmS ScriptRunner sh auto.sh" in the terminal, not sure if it's the same if I run it in node but since it doesn't work manually, I'm guessing that isn't the problem.

Comment: @LukaHorvat Try adding -l option to sh: `screen -dmS ScriptRunner sh -l auto.sh`, or try using bash instead: `screen -dmS ScriptRunner bash -l auto.sh`. If it doesn't work, try running your node inside the script with `screen -dmS GNode -L bash -l -c "exec node server"`.

Comment: I've tried what you said and I've tried all the permutations but no dice. The screen session (if I run it manually) does get terminated as per first line but it doesn't get restarted. Even with a delay and everything.